# Upon registration, redirect new user to Dashboard

Tags: user-registration

How could I redirect someone to the dashboard rather than the front end once they have registered on my site?

**EDIT:**

What I would like to do is to redirect someone to the Dashboard once they have signed in with their username and password.

Many thanks.

Comment: How are you handling the registration. Usually wordpress let the user register and sends a password via mail and then the user logs in to the dashboard.??

Comment: Hi Maruti. Apologies, I have added and EDIT above which explains what I need a little bit further.

Comment: Usually, WordPress redirects the user to the dashboard unless it is coded otherwise. Can you look for a function hooked to the filter **login_redirect** in your functions.php file.
Detail http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

Comment: Maruti, if you add that as an answer I will mark it as such, thanks!

Comment: Hope the solution worked? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, WordPress redirects the user to the dashboard unless it is coded otherwise.

Can you look for a function hooked to the filter **login_redirect** in your `functions.php` file.

For details check the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect_)